# return to the beginning of an if-statement in a loop

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a simple game where the user has to go through a maze.  At the beginning of the maze, I give the user possible routes to take, and ask the user which route to take next.  If the user enters a correct route, I take him to the next route.  If the user enters a wrong route, I print an error message, followed by the prompt again, and read his input again.

I'm having trouble figuring out what to do after I print the error message.  How do I go back to the beginning of the loop?  I did some research and am starting to think that I should use a do-while loop instead, but given the iterations in between (repeating this step until the user finds the exit of the maze), I struggle to figure out exactly how to do that.

Here is my original if-else statement:

```
        printf("Prompt for user input\n");     //step1
        //user input                           
        scanf("%s", &input);                   //step2
        //check input
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            if (strncmp(input, condition) == 0){//do something}
            else{
                  printf("error\n");
                  //need to do steps 1 and 2 again
        }
```

Thank you for your time, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Put steps 1 and 2 inside the loop?

Comment: `continue` skips the rest of a `for` loop, essentially returning to the first statement (if the end condition is not true). For nested loops, only the present loop, not the outer loop.

Comment: Re putting steps 1 and 2 inside the loop: I already tried that, upon printing the error message the program does not go back to steps 1 and 2.

Comment: Your end brackets are missing in the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to wrap it in another loop.

```
bool game_over = false;

do {
    printf("Prompt for user input\n");     //step1
    //user input                           
    scanf("%s", &input);                   //step2
    //check input

    bool input_okay = true;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (strncmp(input, condition) == 0) {
          //do something
        }
        else{
              printf("error\n");
              input_okay = game_over = false;
              break;
    }

    if (!input_okay)
      continue;   // restart do while

    //
} while(!game_over);
```

The flags (defined with the `bool` type from `stdbool.h`) are required to make sure the continue statement is executed in the correct scope (of the `do ... while` loop).

Answer (score 2):

From your question i could understand that you are prompting the user to enter value untill he gives correct answer or he completes the 7 chances.

You can use do while loop for the same:

```
 int chanceCount = 0;  //it will keep track of number of chances user gets

do {
            printf("Prompt for user input\n");    
             //user input                           
            scanf("%s", &input);  

            if (strncmp(input, condition) == 0)
            {
                   //do something
                   break; /* come out of loop, as user gave correct answer*/
            }
           else
           {
                 printf("error try again \n");

             }
            chanceCount ++;
     }while(chanceCount != 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool OK = false
while( ! OK ) {
    printf("Prompt for user input\n");     //step1
    //user input                           
    scanf("%s", &input);                   //step2
    //check input
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            if (strncmp(input, condition) == 0)
            {//do something}
                OK = true
            }
            else
            {
                  printf("error\n");
                  //need to do steps 1 and 2 again
                  OK = false;
            }
    }
}
```